# update query shows error in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

While using an update controller in laravel 4.2 version, it shows the error page and not updated the row

```
public function updatelocation($data=NULL)
{

$GeneralData = array_filter(Input::except(array('_token')));
$validation  = Validator::make($GeneralData, locationModel::$rules);
if ($validation->passes()) 
    {
    $updatedata=array_filter($GeneralData);
    $editid=$data;
    //return ($data);
    $affectedRows = locationModel::where('LId', $editid)->update($updatedata);
    return Redirect::to('locations')->with('Message', 'Location Details Updated Succesfully');
    } else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('editlocation/'.$data)->withInput()->with('Message', 'Some Location Details are missing');
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: Shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." error if i change any of the form entries and update. If i gave the same value as in the database, then it is fine

Comment: post print_r($updatedata) and your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$editid=$data;`

here you have a mistake unfortunately you are not giving it id but passing whole array. You need to pass id from $data array or object.

```
`$editid=$data->id; or $editid=$data['id'];`
```

2. if `$data` is `id` confirm Check your model name It may be first letter capital .
3. Removing where clause `where('LId', $editid)->` put id in merging it in

`$updatedata` array.

This way you can do

```
$locationmodel = locationModel::find($editid);

$locationmodel ->fill($updatedata);

$locationmodel->update(); or $locationmodel->save();
```